# Is it mandatory to set the Invoke's args parameter as Object() always?

Tags: c#

The [`.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.110).aspx) Method requires to set the args parameter as `new object[]`, is that necessary? i mean can i set it as `new string[]` or directly without using an array? for example can i use it like this:

```
        this.Invoke(delegate, "Some text");
```

or like this:

```
        this.Invoke(delegate, new string[] { "Some text"} );
```

or setting it as `new object[]` is a must?

```
        this.Invoke(delegate, new object[] { "Some text"} );
```

apologize if it sounds lame, but every code i checked uses the Object array even the MSDN's, while as i know it's faster to use it as String, however though there must be a reason why everyone uses an Object, that's why i ask. Appreciate your answers in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried any of these? You might also want to look at how the [params keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) works.

Comment: Yes, and all works, but i'm looking for a clean code, as we don't set a string variable as an object, you know what i mean.

Comment: No, I don't know what you mean. If they work, then that's your answer. Unless you had a different question?

Comment: Sir you missed my point, they all works, but my quest was which one is the better and does declare the param as Object is necessary while it can be decalred as a string!

Comment: "Best" based on what? In terms being clean and easy to read (and type), I'd personally go with the first one, but it's a matter of opinion and YMMV. Other people might argue that the first one is hiding the fact that you really passing an `object[]` and therefore might claim the second is more explicit and therefore better.

Comment: yeah, that's what i would think of to "the second is more explicit" but weren't sure as the safe thread is a new subject to me

Comment: Thread safety isn't germane here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.Invoke(delegate, "Some text");` and `this.Invoke(delegate, new object[] { "Some text"} );` causes you to pass in `new object[] { "Some text"}`.

However doing `this.Invoke(delegate, new string[] { "Some text"} );` will cause the object to be wrapped and you will pass in `new object[] { new string[] { "Some text" } }`.

UPDATE: I just tested this and I appear to be wrong, I was 100% sure the behavior was different. All 3 ways of invoking produce the same result when working with `string[]`. The behavior I described only happens when the type is not implicitly convertible, for example when using a `int[]`.

[Here is a example program showing the behavior](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OJrzdz)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing string[]");
        var test = new string[1] {"example"};
        Example(test);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Testing int[]");     
        var test2 = new int[1] {0};
        Example(test2);
    }

    public static void Example(params object[] test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Array Type: {0}", test.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("test[0] Type: {0}", test[0].GetType());
    }
}

/* Outputs:
Testing string[]
Array Type: System.String[]
test[0] Type: System.String

Testing int[]
Array Type: System.Object[]
test[0] Type: System.Int32[]
*/
```

Comment: aha, so the `string` is the best?

Comment: "Best" all depends on what you are trying to do, you did not give enough context to say which way would be the "Best".

Comment: i'm using it with a safe-thread, as my thread access a thread of a textbox

Comment: That has no affect on what would be "best".

Comment: so it's not like `Dim x as String = "something"` and `Dim x as Object = "Somthing"` ?

Comment: No, it is exactly like that for options 1 and 3, but the middle option is not.

Comment: So that would make the second is the best in my case, thank you, that's all  i need

Comment: Unless the function you are pointing at is declared as `string[]` as it's first and only parameter (which I really doubt you have) you should use the first or the last. Or to be more clear, if `delegate` is a `Foo(string bar)` use 1 or 3, if it is `Foo(string[] bar)` use 2.

Comment: yes it's a `string` function, but thanks, you made it pretty clear to me.

Comment: "However doing `this.Invoke(delegate, new string[] { "Some text"} );` will cause" the array to be implicitly converted to `object[]` and passed directly to `Invoke`, without wrapping it in a new array, surely?

Comment: @hvd, whoh, just tested it, did that behavior change in a recent version of .NET? I know for sure it used to do `new object[] { new string[] }`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I know the implicit conversion from `string[]` to `object[]` has been available for a very long time (MSDN documentation for it exists for Visual Studio 2003). I would be surprised about overload resolution changes -- I would expect it to pass the array directly right from the first version -- but the oldest I can check is VS2012, which too passes the array directly. (Of course for `new int[] { ... }` it's an entirely different story, there's no implicit conversion from `int[]` to `object[]`, so that does cause it to be wrapped in an `object[]`.)

Comment: @hvd I would put money on the fact that the `int[]` to `object[]` conversion is what I encountered in the past and is was I was remembering. I updated my answer with correct information.